# show if $r \to b + \varepsilon$ then $\sin(r) = \sin(b)\cos(\varepsilon) + \cos(b)\sin(\varepsilon) \approx (-1)^n\varepsilon$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm looking at circular motion, and looking at the radial vector $r$ and seeing what happens when $r$ changes by a small $\varepsilon$ (if $r$ was initally $b$). I'm trying to form a second order ODE for $\varepsilon$ and I have a $\sin(b+\varepsilon)$ to take care of and the solutions show that: if $r \to b + \varepsilon$ then $\sin(r) = \sin(b)\cos(\varepsilon) + \cos(b)\sin(\varepsilon) \approx (-1)^n\varepsilon$.

I understand the equality part from the double angle formulae but where did the $(-1)^n\varepsilon$ come from?

Comment: What is $n$ supposed to be? Note that $\sin \epsilon\approx\epsilon$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar an integer im assuming - the question does not state it

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about it this must be a typo and I think it should be $\sin(r)\approx (-1)^n\epsilon+\sin(b)$

since $r\to b+\epsilon$$\,$, $b$ could be larger or smaller than $r$, so equivilantley, we could have $\epsilon\gt 0$ or $\epsilon\lt 0\,$, thus:

$\cos(b)\sin(\epsilon)\approx(-1)^n\epsilon$

and $\sin(b)\cos(\epsilon)\approx\sin(b)$

thus:

$\sin(r)=\cos(b)\sin(\epsilon)+\sin(b)\cos(\epsilon)\approx(-1)^n\epsilon+\sin(b)$

Which actually does make sense since it is saying that if $r$ varies slightly, the value $\sin(r)$ changes slightly as well.

Comment: I have edited my answer, and I think it makes sense, but I hope it helps :)

Comment: There are a couple things I don't see. First, if you replace $\cos\epsilon$ with $1$, why wouldn't you replace $\sin\epsilon$ with $0$? Second, you seem to replace $\cos b$ with $1$, I don't see why you do that.

Comment: well $|cos(b)|\le 1$ and since $\epsilon$ is small it dominates the term, so we can "let" $cos(b)=1$, whereas for small $\epsilon$, $\sin(\epsilon)$ behaves very much like $\epsilon$ and it is the dominating term, so we include it.

Comment: I don't see it (and I agree that it is probably a failure in the formulation of the question). It could be that $\cos b=1/10$, say. Then you are saying that $\frac1{10}\sin\epsilon\approx\epsilon$ and that $\sin\epsilon\approx\epsilon$, from where you conclude that $\frac1{10}\epsilon\approx\epsilon$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami
Yes this is because $\epsilon$ is very very small, so multiplying by a number of "moderate" size like $1/10$ makes almost no difference

Comment: @MartinArgerami
and $\sin\epsilon=\epsilon-\epsilon^3/3!+\epsilon^5/5!\pm...$, and every time you square or cube $\epsilon$ it gets much much smaller, thus $\sin\epsilon\approx\epsilon$